# Is there try-catch in ant similar to java

Tags: java, ant

I'm using Invoke task to call java service.
I want to catch if Invoke task fails. Any input is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not certain what a Java "service" is, any Java application can be executed by *another* java application, via the [`<java ...>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task. Have that second application be nothing but a call to your service, which is enclosed in a try block.

Ant:

```
<java classname="TryCallService">
   <arg value="param1"/>
</java>
```

Java:

```
public class TryCallService  {
   public static final void main(String[] params)  {
      try  {
         JavaServiceThatMayCrash.main(params);
      }  catch(TypeOfException1 x1)  {
         //Deal with it here
      }  catch(TypeOfException2 x2)  {
         //Deal with it here
      }
   }
}
```

The `failonerror` attribute of the `java` task defaults to "false". So if the call fails (throws an exception), the build still continues. Set it to "true" if the build should also stop on an error.

Comment: I don't have permission to modify java service.

Comment: I tried this but facing error:   <java classname="com.test.service.db.SimpleDbService" resultproperty="${output}">
      <arg value="${testQuery}"/>
      <arg value="${build.db.name}"/>
      <arg value="${build.db.userid}"/>
      <arg value="${build.db.passwd}"/>
   </java>

Comment: Error:     SimpleDbService does not contain main method

Comment: My java service (SimpleDbService) does not contain main method

Comment: Consider adding more information to your question post describing the service, how it's executed via Ant, and anything else you think might be helpful. I can't help you until I understand this better.

Comment: Service is executed using Invoke task via Ant:

Comment: <invoke command="call" resultpropertyname="intvalue">
    <parameter name="build.rpc.class"  value="com.test.service.db.SimpleDbService" />
    <parameter name="query"  value="${rtp.updates.query}"/>
    <parameter name="build.db.name"  value="${build.db.name}"/>
    <parameter name="build.db.userid"  value="${build.db.userid}"/>
    <parameter name="build.db.passwd"  value="${build.db.passwd}"/>
  </invoke>